# phpunit Functional Tests Error Call to undefined method

Tags: php, symfony, phpunit

I have a question,

I am using phpunit WebTestCase in symfony 3.4

but I can't select any data

and I get

> 1) Tests\BankBundle\Controller\BankControllerTest::testmoneyIn
>   Failed asserting that null matches expected 1.

[I follow this Tutorial](https://symfony.com/doc/2.2/cookbook/testing/doctrine.html)

this is my ControllerTest

```
<?php
namespace Tests\BankBundle\Controller;
use BankBundle\Entity\entry;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase;
class BankControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
    /**
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager
     */
    private $em;

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    public function setUp(): void
    {
        static::$kernel = static::createKernel();
        static::$kernel->boot();
        $this->em = static::$kernel->getContainer()
            ->get('doctrine')
            ->getManager();
    }

    public function testmoneyIn()
    {
        $client = static::createClient();
        $client->request('POST', '/bank/moneyin', array('amount' => 50));
        $bank = $this->em
            ->getRepository('BankBundle:entry')
            ->getId(1);

        $this->assertEquals(1, $bank);
    } 

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    protected function tearDown(): void
    {
        parent::tearDown();
        $this->em->close();
    } 
}
```

Comment: You are trying to assert that`$bank = 1`. But `$bank` is null. Your test is failed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to assert that `$bank = 1`. But `$bank` is null. Your test failed.
For test use, you should always use predictable data. That means, whenever you run the test, you know the expected result. So, you are sure that if your assertion failed, that means, your code is wrong.

Comment: Thank for your Suggest. I will try it